# Android Studio missing native files

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I am new to Android Studio. I have happily used Eclipse for the last 5 years but have to move to Android Studio now.

I have imported my eclipse project and set up the ndk link (I am using ndk-build) and specified my Android.mk file but the project won't compile because it can't find all my source files.

For the line

```
#include "MyFile.h"
```

The error is

```
Error:(9, 24) MyFile.h: No such file or directory
```

Even though the Android.mk file specifies all directories for the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES as it did in Eclipse.

The file "MyFile.h" (just one of many missing files) is definitely in the correct folder but Android Studio doesn't show it in the Project View under Android -> My Project -> cpp

Trying to copy the file into the Project View understandably throws the error "File already exists".

Specifying the path and using:

```
#include "../App/MyFile.h"
```

works but it shouldn't need this because of the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in the make file.

How can I make Android Studio understand my include directories and use all the files that are available in my folder?

Additional info: When searching the directory, the file MyFile.h is included in the search and shows results.

Comment: so you are indignant LOCAL_C_INCLUDES is not recognized by Android Studio but #include "../App/MyFile.h" is recognized? is this correct ?

Comment: yes thats correct